# HTML5 video height shows up differently depending on browser

Tags: html, css

I don't understand why the height attribute results in large differences between browsers.  In firefox it fits my screen, in chrome the video is twice the size and all the other elements no longer fit.

Am I misunderstanding how the height attribute denoted in pixels works or something. I don't understand how my video is not the same size across browsers.

(I'm not zoomed in or out on either browser, ctrl zoom is at 100% on both)

I have other elements next to the video, which is why I use display: inline-block. In chrome those elements no longer fit. (I can fix this with zooming of course, but that's not what I want, I just want the same size across browsers).

```html
<video src="video.mp4" controls  autoplay></video>


video {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 470px;
  margin-top: 1px;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  margin-right: 1px;
  margin-left: 1px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It changed it to this which makes it work across browsers. But I still don't understand why absolute values differ so much and why I need to use responsive design.

```
video {
  display: inline-block;
 width: 100%;
  margin-top: 1px;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  margin-right: 1px;
  margin-left: 1px;
}

.VideoContainer
{
display: inline-block;
  width: 70%;
}
```

Comment: Maybe it's the way you have your neighbouring elements set up. Things like floats can cause issues across browsers, if not done properly. Try using flexbox, see if that helps.